# Install and add custom events of @braze/sdk-web package in sails js/node js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, appboy, braze

how to install and add custom events of @braze/sdk-web package in sails js/node js. As I followed the documentation of braze but sails js server keeps giving error(restarting the server)

Answer (score 0):

`@braze/web-sdk` isn't supported in Node.js environments.

If you post the actual error it'll help find the root cause.